# WordPress rewrite gallery url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am writing a Wordpress gallery with pagination and now have URL like:

> http://example.lt/photo/value/?id=2

I want have:

> http://example.lt/photo/value/id/2

where:

```
value - post name 
photo - static not change
```

I tried permalink settings, but there was no result for my problem, and I think I need to rewrite roles htaccess(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these above any wordpress rules you have in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^photo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /photo/$1/?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```